# Handling schema mismatches in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading a csv file using Spark in Scala.
The schema is predefined and i am using it for reading.
This is the esample code:

```
// create the schema
val schema= StructType(Array(
      StructField("col1", IntegerType,false),
      StructField("col2", StringType,false),
      StructField("col3", StringType,true)))

// Initialize Spark session
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("Parquet Converter")
    .getOrCreate

// Create a data frame from a csv file
val dataFrame: DataFrame =
spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).option("header", false).load(inputCsvPath)
```

From what i read when reading cav with Spark using a schema there are 3 options:

1. Set mode to `DROPMALFORMED` --> this will drop the lines that don't match the schema
2. Set mode to `PERMISSIVE` --> this will set the whole line to null values
3. Set mode to `FAILFAST` --> this will throw an exception when a mismatch is discovered

What is the best way to combine the options? The behaviour I want is to get the mismatches in the schema, print them as errors and ignoring the lines in my data frame.
Basically, I want a combination of FAILFAST and DROPMALFORMED.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I eventually did:
I added to the schema the "_corrupt_record" column, for example:

```
val schema= StructType(Array(
    StructField("col1", IntegerType,true),    
    StructField("col2", StringType,false),
    StructField("col3", StringType,true),
    StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType, true)))
```

Then I read the CSV using PERMISSIVE mode (it is Spark default):

```
val dataFrame: DataFrame = spark.read.format("csv")
                                .schema(schema)
                                .option("header", false)
                                .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
                                .load(inputCsvPath)
```

Now my data frame holds an additional column that holds the rows with schema mismatches.
I filtered the rows that have mismatched data and printed it:

```
val badRows = dataFrame.filter("_corrupt_record is not null")
badRows.cache()
badRows.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `DROPMALFORMED` and follow the log. If malformed records are present there are dumped to the log, up to the limit set by `maxMalformedLogPerPartition` option.

```scala
spark.read.format("csv")
  .schema(schema)
  .option("header", false)
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .option("maxMalformedLogPerPartition", 128)
  .load(inputCsvPath)
```

Comment: where this malformed record gets dumped and stored at which location? Do we need to specify the location as well?